# Reordering parameters and controllers in the URI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I would like all my URLs in codeigniter to start with the first URI segment to be passed to the controller as a parameter.

Here is my use case:

For the url: http://www.example.com/site/page/1

The "Site" would be a parameter passed to the controller "page", "1" is also a parameter (and anything after it).

Would a Mod_Rewrite be more appropriate than codeigniter routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in routes for particular page like

```
       $route['site/page/(:num)'] = 'page/site/$1';
```

Comment: In this case, "site" is a variable that is unknown. Although it could be added as a (:any) instead of "site" in the route?

Comment: $route['(:any)/page/(:num)'] = 'page/$1/$2';